# Shoresh starting with "Vav"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, riddle

What is the **only** ***shoresh*** in *lashon hakodesh* that starts with the letter "Vav"?

Nouns are fair game.

(Don't tell me there is more than one - *Varod* or *Vered* is Aramaic, and the shoresh of *Vidui* does not start with a "vav".)

Comment: I was gonna say ורד (meaning Rose). How do you know (or why do you say) it's aramaic?

Comment: No instance of ורד in Tanach. Appears first in Mishnayos, Braisos, and Midrashim.

Comment: I wonder if R' JD Bleich would hold you spell "Varda" ending with an aleph [for transliterating non-Hebrew] and not a heh [for Hebrew] because it's not Biblical; that's his opinion about "Ilana."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vav vav, which spells 'vav'?
(I thought of this independently but confirmed it [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36864&st=&pgnum=166).)

Comment: Actually it's vav alef vav, but you got the source (or one of them so you get the check.) And for all you "I'll ask a question I know the answer to, answer it and give myself a check"ers: I knew the answer but I feel it is more important to generate genuine learning and research rather than feed everything to others.

Comment: Meaning "hook", I assume?  (The vav in Paleo-Hebrew [ksav ivri] does look like a hook.)

Comment: Absolutely, that is why it is the vav that is used as the all around conjunction. See http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/2720/does-the-vav-hahipuch-also-mean-and-do-all-those-extra-ands-belong-in-the-b/2721#2721

Comment: Is it used Biblically as a verb?  (E.g. tav, which in Paleo looked like an X, means "mark", both as a noun and verb, Ezekiel 9:4.)

Comment: I cannot recall any instance, but I do not know for sure. Let me research it a little ...

Comment: By the way Alex, WAF nailed it "hook", line and sinker! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

vav-ayin-dalet?

Comment: Sorry. Although that is a valid Hebrew word, its shoresh is "yud ayin dalet".

Answer (score 1):

If Shalom gets to use vav ayin dalet (a version of yud ayin dalet), I'll throw in vav hay bais (see Rashi Bamidbar 21:14)

Comment: There's a lot of those, too.

Comment: As well as nouns like valad and veshet.

Comment: Or viter (ותר).

Comment: Although Rashi says the vav is from the Yesod he just means that it is not a prefix. It takes the place of the Yud.

Comment: YDK, it was a nice try and you generated interest in the difference between a letter being "min haYesod" and being the actual letter of the shoresh. Yiyasher Kochacha!